How to copy a specific row of cells from one sheet to another sheet. The row needed to copy is dynamic and defined in another cell
In Excel, I am trying to copy data from sheet1 to sheet2. The specific row number of data I need to copy is defined in a cell on sheet2 as a value. The formula should reference the value of this cell to know which row of data to copy.
In the cell I am trying to copy data to I have tried the formula,
=CONCATENATE("Sheet1!","E",VALUE($B$18))
Which returns Sheet1!E46, but I need it to return the data that is actually in that cell on the other sheet.

Do it with INDEX? Untested but probably correct: =INDEX(Sheet1!E:E, $B$18)
